# Is it possible to create an iOS 8 sharing extension that opens the website in its app?

Tags: ios8, mobile-safari, safari-extension, ios8-extension, ios8-share-extension

I'm building an app, and I was curious if there's a way to open the app when you're on the website through the iOS Safari extension. So, if I'm on a post I'd tap the app icon in the share sheet and I'd pass that to the app to load the post in the app.

I know the Bing app can translate the current website and inject directly into the DOM, so I was wondering what custom logic you can implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no way to open the app from this kind of extension. Extensions can't access `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`, so they can't call `openURL:`. There's an `openURL:completionHandler:` method on `NSExtensionContext`, but it only works in "today" extensions. Share extensions can display a fully custom UI and can save data that's available to their containing app, but they can't actually open that app.